# how to assign returned values into a variable using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have a code that return the max value of each column in the dataframe until now it returns a list of the correct items.

What I want is to assign each item into a variable where this variable is created inside the for loop over the list.

expected result:

- var1=item0
- var2=item1
- var3=item2

where the **var** is a variable created by the iteration over the list.

if i run the code below it crash and return this error:

```
    for i, l in lgdf:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

## code:

```
import pandas as pd

grouped_df=pd.crosstab(df['year_month'], df['event_type'])
lgdf =   list(grouped_df.max())

i = 0
for i, l in lgdf:
    var[i]=l
print(var)
```

Comment: A list is the perfect storage for a list of items, why do you want individual variables instead? Still, see this question for iterating over a list with index: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops

Comment: because i want display each variable in a different label but i do not know how many variables is created so that i want  to iterate over the list

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What's `df`, where is `var` declared? This bit of code won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the comment of @Wups that storing the values in a list (or dictionary) would work as well, you can do the following to create variables within a for loop.

```
for i, l in lgdf:
    exec(f'var_{i} = l')
```